# Changing colors in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find it very frustrating that I can not easily change the color of say, whitespace, or comments in VS Code.  Perhaps there is some feature I don't know about if so, please let me know.

I can go to preferences -> keyboard shortcuts and change those which is great.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to change the text colors other than, somehow figuring out what the key is and manually changing the color associated with that, somewhere, I can't even remember where I've done that before.

So I guess my question is a) is there some feature I'm not aware of?  b) if not is there an extension? and c) if not do the VS Code devs know about this shortcoming?

Comment: search google/SO for `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`

Answer (score 0):

you should go to Preference under the Code menu item under preference click on Settings. Now from the menu on the left click on Workbench - Appearance. There are color settings for many things defined in that file. Scroll thru and look for the setting you want to change.

Comment: Yes, right, this (workbench->appearance->color customizations)  is where I've made some customization before.  (thanks for reminding me how to get there)  However, again, you have to have some knowledge about what you are looking to change and what it's called.  There is autocomplete but still.  There is no user friendly UI that shows you all the things that are set, and allows you to search for them and change them etc.

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color